# Juego del volado (coin flip)

Tags: c#, variables, consola, game, porcentaje

Estoy atorado con un juego donde tengo que preguntarle al usuario si elige Heads o Tails?
luego cuantas veces quieres que tire la moneda, si el usuario elige Heads, tengo que imprimir por consola cuantas veces salio Heads guadar esa cantidad en una variable llamada correctcount y cual es el porciento dependiendo de cuantas veces se tiro la moneda.

Donde estoy atorado es que aunque el usuario elija la palabra  (Tails) el sistema guarda las veces que salio heads y da el prociento con respecto  a heads, he tratado varias forma pero no logro encontrar como guardar la cuenta correcta. Alguien me ayudo pero me acabo de dar cuenta de este problema hasta ahora.

Cualquier ayuda es apreciada. Aqui lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
    {
        String headsOrTailsGuess;
        int numberOfFlips;
        int correctCount;
        int userImput;
        Random CoinFlip = new Random();

        Console.Write("Welcome to the Heads or Tails game " +
            "\nGuess which side will show more times, Heads or Tails?  ");
        
        headsOrTailsGuess = Console.ReadLine();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headsOrTailsGuess))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you need to make a selection to conntinue, try again and select Heads or tails");
            
            headsOrTailsGuess = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (headsOrTailsGuess == "Heads")
        {
            userImput = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            userImput = 1;
        }

        Console.Write("How many times would you like the coin to be flipped? ");

        numberOfFlips = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine());

        correctCount = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++)
        {

            int flip = CoinFlip.Next(0, 2);

            if (flip == userImput)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("Head");
            } 
            
            else 
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("Tail");
                
            }

            if (flip == userImput)
            {
                correctCount++;
                
            }

            

        }

        decimal percentage =  (decimal) correctCount / numberOfFlips * 100;

        Console.WriteLine( "Your guess, " + headsOrTailsGuess + ", came up "  + correctCount + " time (s) \nThat's " + percentage + "%");
        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

yo de nuevo, aquí el detalle está en la impresión, ya que si quieres imprimir los resultados del random tiene que ser por su valor resultante y no por el valor del usuario. En este caso sería:

```
if (flip == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Head");
}else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tail");
}
```

Haciendo esto tiene sentido el mensaje del final